# In row class, column gets overlapped at some width

Tags: bootstrap-4

Here is part of coding. in the row class I have defined a number column for image and form element for all width but still it is overlapped at some width.

```
<div id="contactme" class="container-fluid">
      <h3 style="padding-left:30px; padding-bottom:40px;">Contact me</h3>

      <div class="row padding">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
          <img class="img-responsive" 
                 src="web/photo.jpg"style= "height:500px;">
        </div>
    <!--contact me-->
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-9 col-lg-9 col-xl-9">
          <form action="action/php_page">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="name">Name:&#42;</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" required>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `img-responsive` class in Bootstrap 4. It's been renamed to `img-fluid`